# Changing the value of a checkbox

Tags: jsp, checkbox

I have a check box in my jsp page as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" id="checkbox1" onclick="changevalue(this)"/>
```

Then in my script

```
function changevalue(checkbox)
{
    if(checkbox.value==1)
    {
        checkbox.value=0;
    }
    else if(checkbox.value==0)
    {
        checkbox.value=1;
    }
}
```

But when i submit the form the value of checkbox always is 1.Can any one tell me a solutioin for this.

Comment: Why are you changing the value of the checkbox on clicking it? This seems to be an issue with the logic of your functionality. Surely it would make more sense to check if the checkbox is selected and then use the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that when checkboxes are submitted by a browser, when not checked, they are not even returned. Otherwise, the value attribute associated with them is returned. Thus, simply change the `value` attribute of your checkbox to get a different return value.